# Remove first tag <p> from a html

Tags: php, html

I have 1000 HTML documents, which inside I have

```
$contenido="<p>TFJFA<div>whatsapp</div></p><p>second parragraph</p><p>third parragraph </p><p>night</p>";
```

I need to remove the first `</p>` tag; the result must be:

```
$contenido="<p>second parragraph</p><p>third parragraph </p><p>night</p>";
```

I've tried to use this regular expression, but it doesn't work.

```
$pattern = '/\<p\>.*?\</p\>(.*)/';
$contenido=preg_replace($pattern, '$1'. $contenido);
```

Comment: What do you expect that pattern to match, and what isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern contains an un-escaped `/` within it, and you're also using `/` as your regex delimiter (i.e. `/regex/`). You can either escape the internal `/` (in the closing tag) or use a different delimiter:

```
$pattern = '/<p>.*?<\/p>(.*)/';
```

OR (I like this option better, it's easier to understand - I chose '@' as the delimiter):

```
$pattern = '@<p>.*?</p>(.*)@';
```

Also, instead of replacing that with `$1`, you could just have your pattern as `@<p>.*?</p>@`, replace with `''`, and feed in 1 as the `$limit` argument to `preg_replace`.